# Python connect to Hadoop Kerberos with username-password

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, ssh, hdfs, kerberos

I need connecting to a Hadoop cluster that has a Kerberos authentication using Python 2.7.15. 
 First I connect to the Hadoop Edge Node via SSH:

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy)
client.connect("myhost", port=22, username="myusername_1", password="mypwd_1")
```

Second I ask the Kerberos ticket. Because of company security policy I use different credentials (here "myusername_2" and "mypwd_2").

```
kinitcommand = "echo mypwd_2 | kinit myusername_2@MYDOMAIN"
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(kinitcommand)
```

Third I can run a command as "ls"

```
lscommand = "hadoop fs -ls"
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(lscommand)
```

What I am looking for is a Python library that allows the connection described above without using SSH. 
 I tried hdfs but the class hdfs.ext.kerberos.KerberosClient does not allow user credentials as input, [as the hdfs webpage shows](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). 
 Thank you in advance

Comment: Storing a password in your code is a **security breach**! Open a regular Linux shell via SSH, create a "keytab" file via `ktutil` to store your password on the Edge Node _(w/ restricted access privs)_, then create tickets with `kinit -kt blah.keytab blah@REALM`

Comment: Are you sure the cluster nodes can be reached from your PC? Many corporate policies use the Edge Node both as "jumpoff" node _(to monitor user access)_ and as regular "edge" node _(with all client libraries and conf files ready for use)_

Comment: Typically, Hadoop admins run JupyterHub on an Edge Node to allow analysts to run Python/PySpark/R code on that Edge Node, from their web browser _(and/or run RStudio server for hardcore R users)_ // in some cases , analysts can start their own Jupyter notebook on the Edge then connect to their private Notebook from their PC (on a random port)